# .mdf and web client using REST

Tags: c#, rest, soap, webclient, mdf

This is probably one of the most amateurish questions, but our final project requires us to connect to a SQL Server database (`.mdf`) via a web service (either SOAP or REST) and then consume it and I am having the hardest time wrapping my head around it. So I guess I want to make sure I am even doing the right thing because every time I start I feel I am doing it wrong and have to start over:

1. I created a new library class and connected the `.mdf` through a new ADO entity and allowed Visual Studio to generate the classes.
2. From there I added

   ```
   using System.Runtime.Serialization;
   using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
   ```

   and the attributes

   ```
   [Table(Name = "TABLENAME")]
   [DataContract]
   ```

   above each property.

It's after that I get a bit confused. Do I need a connection string within the library class? The book's chapter on SOAP/REST did not include a database example, but manually coded tables so I might already be off in the wrong direction. None of my searches had anybody approaching it the same way so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand in full as you do not reference what book you are reading. It can be useful to split your problem down into chunks. Always remember to separate your concerns - this is really helpful in visualizing what you want to achieve.

The attributes you are referencing are doing two different things.

Firstly `[Table]`:

You are using linq to sql to query your database. I haven't used this myself but the `[Table]` attribute should be used on your class. This object will represent the table in the database. Your properties will represent the columns in the table and should be decorated with `[Column]` attribute. You should not need to add the name to these attributes if they can be inferred.

To understand more of how this tool works check out the Microsoft [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Secondly `[DataContract]`

This is part of .net serialization and is telling the framework that this class can be serialized to XML (or JSON depending on what tools you are using). Again this attribute should decorate your class and you should use the `[DataMember]` attribute for you properties. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here is a quick example. If your table were to look like:

```
Table name Person:
id int,
firstname nvarchar(256),
lastname nvarchar(256),
```

you would have this class:

```
[Table]
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
   [Column]
   [DataMember]
   public int Id { get; set;}

   [Column]  
   [DataMember]
   public string FirstName { get; set;}

   [Column]
   [DataMember]
   public string LastName { get; set;}
}
```

As per your connection string to the database. If you are testing your class library internally then you need to add your connection string to the `App.config`. If you are referencing it in your web service project then it will need to sit ion the `web.config` file e.g:

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="Dbconnection" 
          connectionString="Server=localhost;       
                            Database=exapleDatabase; 
                            Integrated Security=True" ;
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I would suggest some more reading to get the foundations right. Both of the above are just tools. Understanding the underlying concepts will make these tools easier to use. For example once you understand the SQL that is to be performed by LINQ to SQL you can just as easily write you own queries using plain ADO.net or even use something more modern like Entity Framework. Microsoft will always shield you from the hard work but that sometimes can mean you don't really understand what is happening and in my opinion that will only cause you problems in the long run.

Comment: Thank you that helps demystify quite a bit. This may require a new post, but since it auto generated the code, it put each table in a partial class so now it looks like I have multiple contracts. Is there a way to add multiple contracts in Web.config or do I need to move all the partials to a single complete class?

Comment: You need to follow the link and read up on Linq to Sql. You need to understand how to use the DataContext class to run your queries. The DataContext is the abstraction of your overall database the partial classes represent the tables, the properties of those classes represent the columns. Understanding the abstraction should help you in understanding how to piece it all together.